# Issue with socket.io join room

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have a issue with socket.io with rooms.

See the server code:

This code below is working properly.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

 socket.join("myroom");

 socket.on('chat message', function(data){
  io.in("myroom").emit('chat message', data);
 });


});
```

But I want the user to enter the room after an event.
Like the code below.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

 socket.on('chat message', function(data){
  io.in("myroom").emit('chat message', data);
 });

 socket.on('join', function(name, device, room){
   socket.join("myroom");
 });


});
```

It's almost the same code , but does not work. What am I doing wrong?

The event is being called correctly.

Edit. Added the front-end code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');



   $('#msg_form').submit(function(){
     socket.emit('chat message', $("#m").val(), "myroom");
     $('#m').val('');
     return false;
   });

   $("#user").submit(function() {
      var name = $("#name").val();
      var room = $("#room").val();
      var device = navigator.userAgent;

      if (name === "" || name.length < 2) {
        $("#errors").empty();
        $("#errors").append("Please enter a name");
        $("#errors").show();
      } else {
        socket.emit("join", name, device, room);
        $("#messages").focus();
      }
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: "but does not work" does not tell us what you expect the behavior to be or what you observe the code doing.  It's not a sufficient description of either your desired behavior or what you observe the current code is doing.  Please explain your question and problem better.

Comment: @jfriend00 The messages is not delivery on second code.

Comment: Are you receiving the "join" message before the "chat message"?  Also, your join callback shows three arguments, but there is only one.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, i'm receiving "join" before the "chat message". At this exemple i'm not using any argument, just calling the method join.

If I call the join method on connection works fine, but do not work with events.

Comment: There is something else wrong with your code that you are not disclosing because `socket.join()` works just fine any time after the socket is connected.  I use messages named "joinRoom" and "leaveRoom" in my code to do exactly the same thing you are doing - it works just fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added the client code too.

Comment: Not that this is the main problem, but do you realize that `socket.emit("join", name, device, room);` only sends the first piece of data `socket.emit("join", name);`.  The method .`emit()` only takes two arguments.

Comment: @jfriend00 If i remove the arguments of function a had the same error. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `$("#user").submit(...)` handler, you do not prevent the default action of the form so it is likely that the page is reloaded right after you hit the submit button.  And, this will reset your connection right after you hit join, giving you a newly initialize connection that is not joined into the room.

You can either add `return false;` to that handler or add the `e` argument to the handler and call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the page from reloading when you hit submit.

```
  $("#user").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var name = $("#name").val();
      var room = $("#room").val();
      var device = navigator.userAgent;

      if (name === "" || name.length < 2) {
        $("#errors").empty();
        $("#errors").append("Please enter a name");
        $("#errors").show();
      } else {
        socket.emit("join", name);
        $("#messages").focus();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

I made this small demo to explain, I simulate the client-side event by setTimeout functions:

Server side:

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(9999);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('message', function(data){
  io.in("myroom").emit('message', data);
 });

 socket.on('join', function(name, device, room){
  console.log("new client has joining a room");
   socket.join("myroom");
 });
  });
```

**Client Side:**

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>


var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9999');

setTimeout(function () { console.log("msg emmited to server");
    socket.emit('join');

}, 

    10000);
setTimeout(function () {
 console.log("msg emmited to server");
    socket.emit("message","message from client");
}, 

    20000);

socket.on("message",function(data){
  console.log("message received from server ="+data);
    }
    );

</script>
```